# Add controls at runtime and handle its Click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, handle, eventhandler

I am running the following code, control was made but can not handle.
Why ?

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button Bt = new Button();
        Bt.ID = "ButtonID";                    
        Bt.Text = "Button Text";
        Bt.Click += new EventHandler(this.test);
        i.Controls.Add(Bt);
    }

    protected void test(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Test";
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. "but can not handle" - what does this mean? `test` method is not called?

Comment: The more interesting question is: what is `i`? What happens if you move it to `Page_Init`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - `Page_Load` is acceptable for creation of dynamic controls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Programmatically adding button with an event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387856/asp-net-programmatically-adding-button-with-an-event)

Comment: I agree with @TimSchmelter, what is `i`?  Knowing that might be all the information we need to answer this one.

Comment: @Igor -> `_test_` method Called in `Bt.Click += new EventHandler(this.test);`

Comment: `i` is a `div` that has `runat server` and `ID`. 
I make a button (`Button Bt = new Button();`) and I add it to i (`i.Controls.Add(Bt);`)
This work is done properly.
The problem is that the `test` code can not run while the button is Handel (`Bt.Click += new EventHandler(this.test);`)